# Parsing values in php

Tags: php, mysql, email

so I have a table in which I have email templates, and these email templates can be later fetched for sending emails.

The structure is :-

```
for_status     subject          message
 int             text           text
```

An example entry is :-

```
for_status = 1,
subject = Transaction Status Changed,
message = Hi $user->firstname, this is a test message.
```

Ok, so the problem is, when I send the email with the current `message` and `subject`, it displays in the email `Hi $user->firstname, this is a test message`

Instead of showing, `Hi thefirstname here, this is a test message`.

I'm fetching user details successfully on the same page in the `$user` variable.
What's going wrong here?

Comment: Just because you have a variable inside some text doesn't mean anything. Unless that string gets executed somehow, that variable is just some randomish characters that LOOK like a variable.

Comment: You need to use templates/placeholders as mentioned in the answers. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158743/simple-template-var-replacement-but-with-a-twist), [and this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477398/php-templating-with-str-replace) question can provide some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP will only perform the substitution for you on strings you have coded into your own PHP files, not those that have come from a database or any other source. If it did, that would be a massive security risk!

You will need to perform substitution on your template yourself.

```
// $message is: Hi %{userFirstName}, this is a test message.
$message = str_replace('%{userFirstName}', $user->firstname, $message);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say "table of email templates", is the actual text of the email template in some sort of database?

If this is the case and you have `$user->firstname` in the database, I'm pretty sure its going to spit that out directly.

Answer (score 1):

You need something whats called placeholders. You need to decide what to have as a place holder, I personally use the following:

```
{%first_name%}, this is a test message.
```

Then in your PHP code you just have an array of placeholders & values like this:

```
$arr = array(
   '{%first_name%}' => $user->firstname,
);

//and now replace the body
$body = str_replace(array_keys($arr), $arr, $body);
```

There is a better way of doing this by using already written libraries or using **Regular Expression** to correctly parse, but I will leave that up to you to figure it out.

Comment: ok this seems to be working. But this only works for 1 value. If have like 3 values within the array, it doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: you need to have 3 place holders than as well. if you mean 3 same place holders with different values yes it will not work because its an array and its keys are the place holders you cant have same key and different values